# "The collection has not been initialized" when doing ListItemCollection.getEnumerator()

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, sharepoint-server

I have been having a problem with Javascript and Sharepoint 2013. I have a number of custom list rows that contain date and time values. I want to determine if there are any overlapping date spans. For this, I have written the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(highLightRedundantTimes, "sp.js");
});

var activitiesList;
var siteUrl;

var date;
var startTime;
var endTime;
var clientContext;
var camlQuery;
var listItems;
var enumerator;
var currentListItem;
var itemid;

var sublistItems;
var subenumerator;
var currentSubListItem;
var subdate;
var substartTime;
var subendTime;
var subcamlQuery;
var subitemid;

var ids = [];

function highLightRedundantTimes() {

    siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;

    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);

    activitiesList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Activities');

    camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query></Query></View>');

    listItems = activitiesList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(listItems);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
}


function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    enumerator = listItems.getEnumerator();

    while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
        currentListItem = enumerator.get_current();

        startTime = currentListItem.get_item('ActivityStartTime');
        endTime = currentListItem.get_item('ActivityEndTime');
        date = new Date(currentListItem.get_item('ActivityDate'));
        itemid = currentListItem.get_item('ID');

        subcamlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
        subcamlQuery.set_viewXml('<View>' +
                                    '<Query>' +
                                        '<Where>' +
                                            '<And>' +
                                                '<Eq>' +
                                                    '<FieldRef Name=\'ActivityDate\' />' +
                                                    '<Value IncludeTimeValue=\'FALSE\' Type=\'DateTime\'>' + date + '</Value>' +
                                                '</Eq>' +
                                                '<Neq>' +
                                                    '<FieldRef Name=\'ID\' />' +
                                                    '<Value Type=\'Number\'>' + itemid + '</Value>' +
                                                '</Neq>' +
                                            '</And>' +
                                        '</Where>' +
                                    '</Query>' +
                                '</View>');

        sublistItems = activitiesList.getItems(subcamlQuery);

        clientContext.load(sublistItems);

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onFilterQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
    }
}

function onFilterQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    subenumerator = sublistItems.getEnumerator();

    while (subenumerator.moveNext()) {
        currentSubListItem = subenumerator.get_current();

        substartTime = currentSubListItem.get_item('ActivityStartTime');
        subendTime = currentSubListItem.get_item('ActivityEndTime');
        subdate = new Date(currentSubListItem.get_item('ActivityDate'));
        subitemid = currentSubListItem.get_item('ID');
    }

}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

However, I always get the error "The collection has not been initialized." right after this command: `subenumerator = sublistItems.getEnumerator();` I have already made all variables global and checked my scopes. Obviously, I am missing something but I can't determine what. Can anybody help me here?

EDIT: I ended up using the server side object model with C# instead. If anybody know the answer, still feel free to add it.

Comment: is the activitiesList available in onFilterQuerySucceeded?

Comment: yes it is available

Comment: why are you always  creating a new SP Context?

Comment: sorry that was just from something I tried. I took it out now as the problem persists whether I load the context anew or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that the variable `sublistItems` is re-assigned multiple times (in a while loop), so when `onFilterQuerySucceeded` is called the variable is most likely replaced with another value, which is not yet loaded.

One way to solve this is to pass `sublistItems` into `onFilterQuerySucceeded` as an argument.